# What's best style? '<>' or 'not =' / VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I was under the impression that it was always best to write:

`If Not X = Y then`

then

`If X <> Y then`

but I'm not sure where I did I get this idea:-).

Is there a best? Why do we have two way to do the same thing anyways?

tks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Readability is most important.**

The second seems more natural to me. It seems misleading to use the equal sign and then adding the `Not` to it.

The `Not` IMHO is best used with boolean functions like `IsNumeric(...)` which lends itself to a more natural reading of the code, E.g.,

```
If Not IsNumeric(myNumberString) Then
```

And, I personally prefer using `Not` to `= False` for Boolean tests. E.g., I like...

```
If bFlag1 Then
If Not bFlag2 Then
```

...more than...

```
If bFlag1 = True Then ' <-- (This is totally redundant) = True
If bFlag2 = False Then
If a <> b = True Then ' <-- please don't ever do this
```

Comment: +1 For the 'least' opinion based answer :-)

Comment: Agree here, I also find I now avoid using "<>" in general because I find that having the comparison part of each comparison as a "positive" evaluation that is then inverted with the "Not". The entire reason for it is reading it after the fact.

Comment: +1 for "This is totally redundant" and "please don't ever do this".  It reminds me of `If IIf(a<>b, true, false) Then`, which I actually found in some code once.

Comment: LOL @ "please don't ever do this"! Very complete answer

Answer (score 2):

The first option is to be avoided as confusing.  Someone might think that you meant to write `If (Not X) = Y Then`.

Why do we have two ways?  Because... how could you prevent it?  It's a natural consequence of having the three operators `=`, `<>`, and `Not`.

Answer (score 2):

Besides style and readabilty there is a little difference:

`Not` is a logical operator and `<>` is a relational operator and logical and bitwise operators have a lower precedence than other arithmetic and relational operators (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711633%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

Furthermore the `Not` operator can be overloaded<s>, I think this is not possible for relational operators in `VBA`</s>.

Comment: You _can_ overload relational operators. See 'Overloading' about three quarters of the way down [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think that `If X <> Y Then...` is more expressive (but this is a matter of preference). Also it might be more efficient in terms of condition evaluation, since `If Not X = Y Then...` needs two operations (evaluating the equality and negating the result) rather than one. But, with some code optimisation behind the scene, who knows what *actually* happens?...

However, there are cases when is impossible to avoid the negated condition; for example the `Is` operator does not have a negated form (like `Isn_t` or something), so in this case you need to say `If Not X Is Y Then...`